# Почему нельзя создать объект, если is_constructible говорит, что можно?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть небольшой класс, в котором есть оператор преобразования от `std::initializer_list`. С помощью SFINAE (это же оно?) я проверяю, что `initializer_list` содержит тип, из которого я могу построить value_type. Проверяю с помощью `std::is_constructible` - `STD enable_if_t<STD is_constructible_v<value_type, Ty>, int> = 0`

```
#define STD ::std::

struct default_property {
  public:
    using value_type      = size_t;

  // ...

  public:
    template<class Ty, STD enable_if_t<STD is_constructible_v<value_type, Ty>, int> = 0>
    default_property& operator=(const STD initializer_list<Ty> init_list) {
      if (init_list.size() != 1) {
        throw MI runtime_error(MI_STR("Size will be only '1'. "));
      }

      _index = value_type{*init_list.begin()}; // 103

      return *this;
    }

  // ...

  private:
    value_type _index;
};
```

Но получаю ошибку (использую g++ 11.2.0):

```
error: narrowing conversion of '* init_list.std::initializer_list<int>::begin()' 
from 'const int' to 'mi::detail::_descriptor::default_property::value_type' 
{aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Werror=narrowing]
  103 |       _index = value_type{*init_list.begin()};
```

Я думал, что если `std::is_constructible` возвращает `true`, то я 100% могу создать один тип из другого и не получить ошибок.

> If T is an object or reference type and the variable definition T obj(std::declval()...); is well-formed, provides the member constant value equal to true. In all other cases, value is false.

Comment: С `is_convertible` тоже не получается

Comment: `#define STD ::std::` Зачем? :(

Answer (score 2):

У вас вылавливается несоответствие при преобразовании знакового типа в беззнаковый. Но в принципе беззнаковый тип из знакового вполне строится :)

Можете указать явное приведение типа с помощью круглых скобок или не указывать вовсе никакое:

```
_index = value_type(*init_list.begin());

_index = *init_list.begin();
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Answer (score 2):

Фигурные скобки `value_type{ .. }` при вызове конструктора обязательно кидают предупреждение преобразования типа аргумента. После проверки на отрицательность поставьте круглые. Круглые скобки не дают предупреждений.

```
if ( * init_list.begin() < 0 )
  throw ;
_index = value_type(*init_list.begin());
```

Answer (score 1):

Вижу две проблемы:

- `std::is_constructible_v<..., Ty>` проверяет конструируемость с аргументом `Ty &&`. А вам надо `std::is_constructible_v<..., const Ty &>`.
- `std::is_constructible_v<T, P...>` проверяет на валидность `T x(std::declval<P>()...)`. С круглыми скобками, а не с фигурными.

  Поэтому меняйте `{...}` на `(...)`. Или вместо `is_constructible_v` пишите свой шаблон, который проверял бы фигурные скобки...

  Еще, `T x(...)` и `T(...)` - не одно и то же. Но похоже что второй умеет все то же, что и первый, и плюс кое-какие менее безопасные преобразования (которые `is_constructible_v` не пропустит). Но в этом я проблемы не вижу.